# JavaScript getting the parent element of WebGLRenderer

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, three.js

Using Three.JS, how do I get the parent element of the renderers canvas DOM element?

I can get the DOM Element using renderer.domElement. However if I try to reference renderer.domElement.parentElement I get null.

I have done:

```
console.log(renderer.domElement)
```

and I can see in the console output (when I expand the object) in the list:

```
parentNode: div#applause-top-team1.dash-space
```

So I can't figure out why I am getting null.

Comment: parentNode vs parentElement?

Comment: Hello. Both parentNode and parentElement has the same result.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? If I understand it correctly, you might have something like `<div id="parent"><canvas id="webgl_canvas" /></div>` and you want to grab the div tag. Is that correct?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bV29a/

Comment: Hi Grant, thanks for your response. I want to get the height of the element which contains the canvas for resizing the 3d objects fluidly.